# Angular: Setting an emptied string to a default value does not update the bound text field properly if the field previously had the default value

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular2-changedetection

I'm using a SET method to set my bound value to 'DEFAULT' if we ever attempt to set it to an empty string. The bound text input behaves properly in every scenario, EXCEPT if the text field already says 'DEFAULT' and I "select all + delete" that value. The bound value properly gets set back to 'DEFAULT' immediately, but the input field remains empty.

[image: The get/set methods]

[image: the template]

Here's a stackblitz showing the issue
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a9j8tv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

If you have 'DEFAULT' and you select all and delete, you can see that the input stays empty, but the span which is bound to the same value properly shows the newly re-set 'DEFAULT' value.

Why does this happen?
Is there a work around?

Comment: No one has any suggestions here?

Comment: To be clear, the issue is that the input and the span don't agree on what the value of "testString" is when this scenario is triggered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Inherent error

The [`ngModel`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/13.0.2/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L136) directive uses [`@Input`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/13.0.2/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L178) and [`@Output`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/13.0.2/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L204) to obtain the value and emit the change event. So binding a function like setter or getter to a directive like `[ngModel]` with default change detection strategy would trigger the function for each change detection.

To replicate this error, plug in a `console.log` in the getter, type some value and keep pressing backspace in the `<input>` and let go. You could see the `console.log` messages keeps getting printed.

Error replication: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jlpq84?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

---

#### Why isn't 'DEFAULT' inserted on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>

As said before, the `ngModel` directive uses `@Input` and correspondingly the [`ngOnChanges()`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/13.0.2/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L220) hook to fetch any changes to the value from `<input>` tag. One important thing to note is [`ngOnChanges()`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) **won't** be triggered if the value hasn't changed<sup>(1)</sup>.

We could try to split the two-way binding `[(ngModel)]` to `[ngModel]` input and `(ngModelChange)` output.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  public testString: string;

  onChange(value: string) {
    this.testString = value === '' ? 'DEFAULT' : value;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" [ngModel]="testString" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" />
```

Still error prone: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-76jrzn?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Here the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> any string other than 'DEFAULT' would insert 'DEFAULT' as expected. But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> 'DEFAULT' would result in empty `<input>` box due the `ngOnChanges()` issue discussed above.

---

#### Solution

One way to achieve expected behavior is to *not* depend on the `ngModel` directive's `ngOnChanges()` hook to set the value, but to do it ourselves manually. For that we could use an Angular [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#syntax) in the `<input>` and send it to the component for further manipulation.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  public testString: string;

  public onChange(value: string, inputElem: HTMLInputElement) {
    this.testString = value === '' ? 'DEFAULT' : value;
    inputElem.value = this.testString;
  }
}
```

```html
<input
  type="text"
  #myInput
  ngModel
  (ngModelChange)="onChange($event, myInput)"
/>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hufx3e?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Here the `#myInput` is the template reference variable. If this feels hacky, you'd need to know using `ngModel` to manipulate `<input>` is in itself called [template driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms). And it's quite legal to manipulate the template ref directly.

With all that said, IMO in cases where such input manipulation is needed, I'd recommend you to use the Angular [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) instead. It provides a more granular control over the input.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> The `ngOnChanges()` won't be triggered if the `previousValue` and `currentValue` of the respective `@Input` variable's [`SimpleChange`](https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChange) object hasn't changed.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation of what is going on with the ngModel directive. That was definitely the piece of the puzzle that I was missing.

I think the important piece of the onChange method is that it specifically sets the input element's value rather than relying on ngModel binding.

Keeping the test logic in the setter (or otherwise outsourcing that logic) still seems to show the desired result

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xd9trm?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @Leviathan3: Ofcourse it's similar to calling functions to adjust and get the value. But note that you'd still run into the same issue I mentioned at the start of the answer. The interpolation `{{ testString }}` would trigger the getter multiple times which might lead to performance issues later: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njkjye?file=src/app/app.component.html). Just a rule of thumb, try to avoid using functions, setters and getters for property binding (eg. `[ngModel]="testString") and interpolation `{{ testString }}`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue comes from `ngModel`. That since the `''` value manipulating to the `DEFAULT`, which is the latest value that has been fired by `ngModel`, `ngModel` does not realize the value change to fire new value changed event.

How to workaround;

I have assigned the changed value directly to the variable in the `setter` before comparison. Then set a minimal timeout to `ngModel` could update its existing value.
Then when I compare the new value and change it back to `DEFAULT` in the case of `''`, `ngModel` realizes the value change and fires the new value changed event. This updates both representations.

[Please find updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kacrnr?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: That doesn't seem to explain why it works in every other scenario.

Typing anything other than 'DEFAULT' into the field, then doing the select all + delete, gets the correct behavior even though the input is still focused

Comment: @Leviathan3 you are right, that I have not realized this behavior.

Comment: As I understand; since the previous emitted value is the same as the actual value on the ngModel update method (which we are manipulating to DEFAULT when we delete all in once), ngModel does not fire the new value update event. Because there is no value update from ngModel, span text keeps the latest fired value as DEFAULT, and the input stays empty.

Comment: @Leviathan3 Could you please check the update. This may fit you.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Using setTimeout of 0 to force trigger a change (as in your staackblitz) does seem to solve the issue too.